# PowerShell - Return True if string matches a condition

Tags: powershell

How do I return a True value from PowerShell if a string matches conditions?

Example: If the first line of the text file is Success then PowerShell will return True condition else False.

Here the code I wrote:

```
IF ((get-content -path $outPath3 -first 1) -like 'Successfully generated*'){$Time=Get-Date}
Else {Send-MailMessage xxxxxxxx}
```

Here the message returns from PowerShell. What is wrong here?

> Get-Content : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'first'.

Comment: What are you asking here. The general question about booleans or your specific issue at hand with Get-Content

Answer (score 3):

Just return the result of the comparison:

`$a = ($something -eq $something_else)`, etc.

In a function use the `return` statement.

In your example:

```
$a = ((get-content -path '.\file.txt' -first 1)-eq "Success")
```

Maybe in simpler words: The result of a comparison, match, etc. is already a true/false value. So with your string match condition:

```
if ($string -match "something")  # The term in brackets is a true/false value
{
    # Statement is True
}
else {
    # Statement is False
}
```

Comment: In PowerShell you don't actually need to use the return statement to return a result from a function. The result is always whatever was put into the pipeline. The return statement is only needed when you want to break out of a function early.

Comment: @ChrisBarber I want to pass TRUE/FALSE to IF statement

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is covered in the comments and came to light when you updated your question. [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Get-Content) did not support the `-TotalCount` parameter until 3.0. `-First` is an alias for `-TotalCount`. Running 2.0 I can simulate your issue.

```
PS C:\Users> Get-Host | Select version

Version
-------
2.0

PS C:\Users> Get-Content C:\temp\anothertext.txt -first
Get-Content : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'first'.
At line:1 char:43
+ Get-Content C:\temp\anothertext.txt -first <<<<
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-Content], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand
```

Hopefully the file is not too big. If not then you can just pipe into `Select-Object` or just use array indexing.

```
if((get-content -path $outPath3)[0] -like 'Successfully generated*')
if((get-content -path $outPath3 | Select -First 1) -like 'Successfully generated*')
```

The drawback in both cases is the whole file will be read into memory to just to drop the rest of it.

Comment: Why not use `Select-String` to return true on the match of the desired characters?

Comment: @user4317867 Mostly because the condition was on the first line. Do not know if that text would appear somewhere else and this is simpler given that possibly. Also explains why what he was doing was not working.

Comment: I used the if((get-content -path $outPath3)[0] -like 'Successfully generated*'),but the result not correct. Then i wrote script to this: IF ((get-content -path $outPath3 ) | Select -Index 0 | Where-Object { $_ -like 'Successfully generated*'}) and it works. Thanks

Comment: The code works for me so I am not sure why you had to go through that trouble. `IF (((get-content -path $outPath3 ) | Select -Index 0) -like 'Successfully generated*')` the where is not required.

Comment: This code also works and I might be way off but should perform better.  `IF(Get-Content .\z1.txt | Select-String -Pattern 'Successfully' -Quiet){"Match found!"}Else{"Did not find text"}`

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what sort of conditions you want to check, you can use any of the PowerShell comparison operators to get a true/false result (see [about_Comparison_Operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/hh847759.aspx) for details).

For example, you could check if a string matches exactly using the `-eq` operator:

```
if ($InputString -eq $StringToMatch) {
    // TRUE
}
else {
    // FALSE
}
```

Note: PowerShell comparison operators are case insensitive. If you want your comparison to be case sensitive you should prepend the operator with "c", for example, `-eq` becomes `-ceq`.

Comment: The `-First` flag was only added in PowerShell 3.0. Your error suggests that you are on Powershell 2.0. To get around this you can use `(Get-Content -Path $outPath3)[0]` to get the first line. Note that this method actually loads the whole file.